# Can React-Router handle more than 20k paths?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am migrating an ASP.NET Web Form site to React + ASP.NET Core API.

In the ASP.NET Site, customers were subscribing to the system by filling a form in which they were entering in a field a unique URL for their profile (such as `"mydomain.com/CustomerURLX"`).

The ASP.NET server script was creating a physical folder on the server, such as `"mydomain.com/CustomerURLX"`, `"mydomain.com/CustomerURLY"`. Once the folder was created, the script was also creating in that folder a single file called default.htm that was redirecting to ie:

- `"mydomain.com/loadCustomerProfile.aspx?ID=1"`
- `"mydomain.com/loadCustomerProfile.aspx?ID=2"`

The customers were using these URLs to access in a more friendly manner their profile on our web site.

All of the customers info are stored in a Database:

```
ClientID: 1 | MainURL: CustomerURLX
ClientID: 2 | MainURL: CustomerURLY
ClientID: 3 | MainURL: CustomerURLZ
etc.
```

So the question is, in React, would it be possible to query the database, then from the query result, to loop and create multiple Routes like `"mydomain/CustomerURLX"`, etc. that would then redirect to `"mydomain.com/loadProfile/ID"`? The database contains more than 20k customers rows (so more than 20k routes would be created), would it be a good practice in React regarding performance? Would it be better to create a local json file containing all customers URLS to create routes? Would it still be a good practice to create more than 20000 routes scanning a json file? Should I continue, like I was doing with ASP.NET, to create physical folders on the server for my redirect instead of using the React-Router? I am using `react-router-dom@6.20.0`.

Comment: No, you don't need 20k routes for 20k customers. You can just use a single URL with a path parameter to "capture" the customer id from the URL. It is called [dynamic segment](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#dynamic-segments) in react router terminology.

Comment: I wish customer to use a friendly url to access their profile, such as mydomain.com/CustomerURLX, these URLs will then redirect to a profile component passing the ClientID to load their profiles, so I need to create many paths without IDs first

Comment: `CustomerURLX` is similar to ID. The general idea remains the same that it can be done using a single route.

Comment: @Phil An id does not need to be a number

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a static route path in the app for each and every possible customer id value, this would be incredibly wasteful, difficult to read/maintain, and not efficient or ***DRY***.

You should instead render a single route with a [dynamic path](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#dynamic-segments).

Instead of this

```
...
<Route path="/loadProfile">
  <Route path="1" element={<Customer />} />
  <Route path="2" element={<Customer />} />
  <Route path="3" element={<Customer />} />
  ...
  <Route path="9999" element={<Customer />} />
  <Route path="10000" element={<Customer />} />
  <Route path="10001" element={<Customer />} />
  ...
  <Route path="19998" element={<Customer />} />
  <Route path="19999" element={<Customer />} />
  <Route path="20000" element={<Customer />} />
</Route>
...
```

Use this

```
...
<Route path="/loadProfile">
  <Route path=":customerId" element={<Customer />} />
</Route>
...
```

or

```
...
<Route path="/loadProfile/:customerId" element={<Customer />} />
...
```

Use the [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params) hook in the routed component, `Customer` in this example, to read the current `customerId` path parameter value.

```js
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const Customer = () => {
  const { customerId } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    // logic to fetch/load specific profile
  }, [customerId]);

  ...

};
```

Comment: the possible variable paths are not under /LoadProfile/X, they are at the ROOT level directly (mydomain.com/variablePathX). I need 20k folders at the ROOT level created from my database to be handled to redirect to a LoadProfile component... I may have found the solution if you look at the WildCard Component reply below

Comment: @Phil Dynamic paths, and e.g. dynamic path segments can exist anywhere within the router structure, including the root directory. `<Route path=":id" element={....} />` is perfectly valid, so long as any generated `id` values don't collide with other routes at the same depth in routing tree. If you prefer using a [wildcard splat](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#splats) then it's still it suggested to use `const { "*": splat } = useParams()` to access the path *and then* apply string functions. Better to be more explicit though with a named path parameter though.

Comment: @Phil Also, using the `ClientID` directly as the URL path parameter you can render the `LoadProfile` component directly, no need to "process & redirect" to another route, you're already there and can just load the appropriate profile data as necessary. I'm not saying your solution won't work... it just seems like a lot of extra work and re-implementation of "route matching" that React-Router can handle for you right out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found a solution using the wildcard route from the react router, like:
{
path: '*',
element: WildCardPath
}

Then, the WildCardPath component would be like:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const WildCardPath: React.FC = () => {
    const { pathname } = useLocation();
    const splitLocation = pathname.split('/');
    // make sure it is a single sub folder (such as mydomain.com/xyz),
    // avoid looking for client url if wildcard url contains more than 1 sub folder (like mydomain.com/abc/xyz)
    if (splitLocation.length > 2) {
        console.log('redirect to the 404 component');
    } else {
        const possibleClientURL = splitLocation[1];
        //fetch API and check if the database contain a row with MainURL=possibleClientURL
        //if API returns a row, redirect to a LoadProfile component with ClientID as param
        //if API returns no row, redirect to the 404 component
    }
    return <div>WildCardPath</div>;
};

export default WildCardPath;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Drew.
So, I can setup the wildcard route back to my original Error404 component, and have a new :clienturl path like this:

{
path: ':clienturl',
element: `<ClientURL />`
},
{
path: '*',
element: `<Error404 />`
},

Then ClientURL component would be like:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const ClientURL: React.FC = () => {
const { clienturl } = useParams();
//fetch API and check if the database contain a row where client.MainURL=clienturl, if yes it will return a row with ClientID
//if API returns a row, load client profile using ClientID
//if API returns no row, show Error404 component
return <div></div>;
};

export default ClientURL;
```